# Fieldset растягивается по ширине контента. Как править?

Tags: html, css, html5

Вопрос на засыпку, господа верстальщики :)

Как наладить правильное отображение `fieldset` и в остальных браузерах?

https://jsfiddle.net/zd8m58s5/2/

```css
.fix{
  min-width: 0;
}

.width-30{
  width: 300px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 15px;  
}

.width-500px{
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  background: aquamarine;
}

.overflow{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p>Fieldset - штука жесткая.</p>
<p>Благодаря стандартным стилям он растягивается по ширине контента, не смотря на четкие указания width. Нашел информацию о том, что все это из-за <code>min-width: -webkit-min-content; и т.п вендоры</code>. Окей, сбросил значение на 0 (в примере - класс .fix), проблема ушла в Chrome, но Firefox по прежнему тупит. В других браузерах пока не проверял.</p>


<p class="overflow">Этот fieldset будет растягиваться на всю ширину контента, не смотря на width: 500px;</p>
<fieldset class="width-30">
  <div class="width-500px"></div>
</fieldset>


<p class="overflow">Этот fieldset правильно отображается в Chrome, но, не в Firefox</p>
<fieldset class="width-30 fix">
  <div class="width-500px"></div>
</fieldset>

<p class="overflow">С этим блоком все збц в любом браузере</p>
<div class="width-30">
  <div class="width-500px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: добавляйте разметку стили и все необходимое **непосредственно** в вопрос

Comment: _Как наладить правильное отображение и в остальных браузерах?_ - в каких остальных?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

`fieldset { display: inline-block; }`

И уберите класс fix.

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло...